# jquery load() doesnt work at all in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, load

Google is full of this question but none of the other pages help me.

I've tried changing jquery versions, tried doing the whole var $j = jQuery.noConflict();, tried rearranging JS/jquery scripts, tried the  no caching thing suggested by jquery website but still my load() doesn't work.

```
<a onclick="loadCont('canyou.php');">Can you help us</a>


function loadCont(file){
$j("#maincont").load(file);
alert(file);
return false;
}
```

As always it loads on every other browser except IE8. The alart() is there for IE8 debugging, and the file is passed successfully, its just not loaded into #maincont

Any help aboutthe code or replies appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you see a hit on the server when you try this in IE8?

Comment: Look at the server's access log.

Comment: Or use Fiddler to see if the request is hitting the network. An invaluable tool. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: used fiddler2 and yes it is being recieved by the server, result: 200

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this up a little differently. Use the following code and see if you get any results.

HTML

```
<!-- link with ajax target in href -->
<a class="loadlink" href="canyou.php">Can you help us</a>
```

jQuery

```
<html>
<head><title>can you</title></head>
<body>
    <!-- we only want to load content from this div -->
    <div id="content">This is the only content we want returned...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

If canyou.php contains a full html skeleton with `<html>` and `<body>` tags then you should have jQuery parse out only the HTML you want from that page and discard the rest (you don't want to shove `<html>` or `<body>` tags into your #maincont div).  You can have jQuery do this by adding a space then a selector after the URL parameter in the load() method.  Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>can you</title></head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        This is the only content we want returned...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what the new load call would look like:

```
$('#maincont').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content');    // Only get the content in #content div
```

Comment: no luck with that, just loads the content page "canyou.php" in the same window

Comment: Is canyou.php a full HTMl document with doctype/html/body tags? If so, I think i've run into this problem before. Please check out my updated answer and let me now if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in your JS somewhere.  Can you send a link to this app or paste your code somewhere (http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Found a few problems. First, if you're loading jQuery into the variable $j using noConflict() then you should be consistent in using that var - just using '$' will no longer work. Also, you're passing the event object in as 'E' but referencing it as 'e'. Finally, your click handler is being executed before the DOM is loaded. You should wrap jquery statements in an onload handler so they are not executed until DOM is ready. I created an updated bin at http://pastebin.com/mf2tUXtx.

Comment: If that code doesn't work then check your styleswitcher.js and formcheck.js files. Maybe there is an error occuring in one of those fiels that is interfering with things. You can start by commenting out those files and seeing if the ajax works when they are not present. If so, you know the problem lies in one of those files.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and yes i thought I had changed all the $ to $j, guess i flipping missed that one! ill try your updated code now :)

Comment: wil lstart trying the commenting out as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

the letter `j` between `$` and `(.` is it normal ?

is it not `$("#maincont").load(file);`

I use load with IE8... it works good personally

Answer (score 0):

Yo Bro. You forgot e.preventDefault();

If you want to have a link open up in a div on your **current** page, for ex:

`<a class="loadlink" href="canyou.php">Can you help us</a>`

Your jQuery should look like this::

```
$("a.loadlink").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //this prevents the redirect that the <a> tag makes on default

// then enter the rest of your jQuery here:
var file = $(this).attr("href");
$("#maincont").load(file);
});
```

That should work 'plug-n-play'.